Error TS18028 while compiling ts to js, tsconfig is almost empty
I initialised a TS package with no preset.
tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}

dev command

"dev": "tsc-watch --noClear index.ts --outDir ./ --onSuccess \"node ./index.js\""

Everything was going well until I installed the redis package. After that I started to have this error.
error TS18028: Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.
And can't understand how to resolve it. No changes to the tsconfig did anything.

Fixed it this way
dev command

"dev": "tsc-watch -p ./tsconfig.json --noClear --outDir ./ --onSuccess \"node ./index.js\"",

tsconfig.json

{
  "files": ["index.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node"],
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "CommonJS"
  }
}

